# El significado de "por oposición al tema"

Tags: significado

Una de las definiciones de "[rema](https://dle.rae.es/rema)" en RAE es "parte de un enunciado que contiene información nueva, por oposición al tema". No consigo entender la parte donde dice "por oposición al tema".

Parece que "por oposición a" significa "as opposed to", "in contrast to", "in opposition to", "versus" o "by opposition to" en inglés, pero no sé cuál de estas definiciones en inglés es la más adecuada en este contexto. Y, me pregunto de qué "tema" se trata en la definición de RAE. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso significa "as opposed to". [*Tema* y *rema*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tema_y_rema) son una pareja de términos contrapuestos, que se definen uno en relación con el otro. El *tema* al cual se refiere el DLE es la definición 9 de *[tema](https://dle.rae.es/tema?m=form)*.

> 9. m. Ling. Parte de un enunciado que presenta cierta información como conocida, por oposición al rema.

*Rema* es una palabra técnica, específica de la lingüística. *Tema* es una palabra mucho más común y genérica, pero en lingüística particularmente significa lo mismo que *tópico*. El tema o tópico, en lingüística, es aquello de lo cual se habla; el rema o comentario es aquello que se dice del tema (información nueva).

En inglés también se dice "theme and rheme" y se utilizan los sinónimos "topic and comment".

Comment: !Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones !